# Can malicious app read private variable from my App?

Tags: authentication, android

I have a local object "Login" (with a password and id) in my activity and I would like to know if I launch a fragment and use a setter to initialized the fragment, is it secured ? Can a malicious app read the object Login ? even if it's private with a root device ? Like this :

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new dialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setLogin(login);
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
```